# Convert JavaScript Get Request to PHP Curl

Tags: javascript, php, curl, php-curl

My PHP Curl code is not returning an error or any response text.  The JavaScript code I based it off of returns a Json Array.

### PHP Curl

```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

  $subscriptionKey = '';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://southcentralus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", $subscriptionKey));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  if($response === false)
  {
      echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }
  else
  {
      echo 'Operation completed without any errors<br>';
      echo "Response: $response";
  }
  $voices = json_decode($response);

  curl_close($ch);
```

### PHP Results

### [image: Php Results Image]
Working Javascript

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var subscriptionKey = '';
    request.open('GET', 'https://southcentralus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list', true);

    request.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey)
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            const response = this.response;
            const data = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(data);
        } else {
            window.console.log(this);
        }
    };

    request.send()
```

### JavaScript Results

[image: JavaScript Output Image]

I changed `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true (thanks to Lucas's comments) and now get a 401 error.  This puzzles me because it is the exact same URL and Subscription key.

Comment: Have you tried adding `echo` statements earlier in your script to see how far through it gets?  If neither the `if` or `else` echo statements are being triggered, that suggests there's a problem earlier in the execution.  I'd begin with an `echo` right on line 1 and a few points in between to see how far through it's getting...

Comment: @lucas "Operation completed" prints out.  I probably should try turning on all errors when I get home.

Comment: Is the word "Response:" printing out?  I don't see why the 'operation completed' line would print, but no the one immediately after.
BTW, if the url in question is returning a 401 with no body, I'd expected the variable `$response` to be an empty string, because CURLOPT_HEADER isn't true.

Comment: @lucas it is getting printed.

Comment: Can you paste the exact output you're seeing from both the PHP & javascript?  Also is `subscriptionKey` definitely an empty string in bith cases?

Comment: @lucas setting CURLOPT_HEADER  to true now returns a 402 error.  Very strange considering the urls and subscription keys are the same.  Note:  I did not include the subscription key in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array for `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` takes one item per header, rather than separate items for key & value.  So in this case, try:

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:
> $subscriptionKey"));

Comment: Brilliant!!  I would have never that to do that.  Thanks for you persistence.